# Accessing IPInterfaceProperties GatewayAddresses on MAUI results in a PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, maui

This code I have accesses the Gateway Addresses after retrieving all of the Network Interfaces.

```
var interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (var networkInterface in interfaces)
{
     if (networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) continue;
     if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up) continue;
     var ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
     if (ipProperties.UnicastAddresses == null) continue;
     var gatewayIpAddressInfo = ipProperties.GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
     foreach (var ipAddressInfo in ipProperties.UnicastAddresses)
     {
         // do something
     }
 }
```

The code runs smoothly on Xamarin.Forms (Android), however I receive an exception while running the same code in MAUI:

```
var gatewayIpAddressInfo = ipProperties.GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
```

I've got everything set up right, and I'm testing on an Android device. This code should function as intended, according to [System.Net.NetworkInformation's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.gatewayipaddressinformation?view=net-7.0) documentation.

Is this issue occurring because I'm using a DotNet preview version?

[image]

What am i supposed to use then?

Dotnet version: **8.0.100-preview.6.23330.14**

Android API level: **33**

Comment: Please post error/warning messages as copy/pastable text (rather than an image). See the last line of the warning: Its a call that is only valid starting with Android API 21. Now, I understand that you are on API 33, but that is the *maximum* version known at build time, not the *minimum*. If you google that line (starting with the error number), what suggestions do you find? Sounds to me like its warning you that you need to add an if-check before it, to make sure running on at least API 21. [My best guess; I haven't looked into this.] It isn't an *error*; can ignore if require at least 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. But in the xamarin forms, I always get null. And in the maui source code, you will find this:

```
[UnsupportedOSPlatform("android")]
public abstract GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection GatewayAddresses { get; }
```

So this api can't run on the android. If you want to get the GatewayIPAddress on the android, you need to use the native code. Such as:

```
private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        var address = GetGateway(Android.App.Application.Context);
#endif

    }

#if ANDROID
    public Java.Net.InetAddress GetGateway(Android.Content.Context context)
    {
        Android.Net.ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (Android.Net.ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.ConnectivityService);
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.M)
        {
            // GetActiveNetwork() requires M or later.
            return null;
        }
        Android.Net.Network activeNetwork = connectivityManager.ActiveNetwork;
        if (activeNetwork == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var routes = connectivityManager.GetLinkProperties(activeNetwork).Routes;
        foreach (Android.Net.RouteInfo route in routes)
        {
            if (route.IsDefaultRoute && !(route.Gateway is Java.Net.Inet6Address))
            {
                return route.Gateway;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
#endif
```

And the result when I tested it:

[image]